# MySQL query to select from multiple table and insert in one

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 5 tables: A, B, C, D, E.
Let each table contain an 'email' field.
Now we want to INSERT all the emails in A which is present in any of C, D, E but NOT in B.

Sample queries:

```
CREATE TABLE a (email VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE b (email VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE c (email VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE d (email VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE e (email VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO b (email) VALUES ('a@b.com'), ('c@d.com');
INSERT INTO c (email) VALUES ('a@b.com'), ('e@f.com'), ('e@f.com');
INSERT INTO d (email) VALUES ('a@b.com'), ('c@d.com'), ('g@h.com');
INSERT INTO e (email) VALUES ('c@d.com'), ('g@h.com'), ('i@j.com'), ('i@j.com');
```

This is what I tried:

```
INSERT INTO a (email)
SELECT
c.email
FROM
c
LEFT JOIN b ON c.email = b.email
WHERE b.email IS NULL
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT
d.email
FROM
d
LEFT JOIN b ON d.email = b.email
WHERE b.email
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT
e.email as email
FROM
e
LEFT JOIN b ON e.email = b.email
WHERE b.email IS NULL;
```

Comment: "present in C, D, E", does that mean that an email has to in both C and D and E, or in just any of C, D and E?

Comment: It could be in any of C, D or E

Comment: Currently we have close to 10 million user in B, 20 million C, 30 million each  in D and E. So we need to do it with highly optimized way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is almost a direct translation of your description:

```
insert into a(email)
    select email
    from ((select email from c) union
          (select email from d) union
          (select email from e)
         ) cde
    where not exists (select 1 from b where b.email = cde.email);
```

Note:  This uses `union` intentionally to remove duplicates.  If you know there are no duplicates in `c`, `d`, `e` or if you want duplicates, then use `union all` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Union all Emails from C,D and E and then discard result which are not present in B:

```
INSERT INTO a (email)
select * from 
(
    SELECT c.email FROM c
    UNION 
    SELECT d.email FROM d
    UNION 
    SELECT e.email FROM e
) as p where p.email not in ( select email from b);
```